# How can I show my client a node js website

Tags: javascript, node.js, client

I have a nodejs app, which I made for my client, I want to show him his website on his machine (we live at different sides of the globe) Is there any way it is possible?

Comment: Put it on github

Comment: Use https://ngrok.com/

Comment: You could use heroku

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty long winded question. There are a couple different solutions to this.

1: You could host a server locally and then open up some firewall ports to allow traffic to route information from your IP address on port 80 or 443 to your application. This is pretty risky though and would need to be secured on your end to prevent intrusion. This would also mean that anytime your IP changes from the ISP you would either need to update the customer with the new IP or use a domain name that is being updated with something like dyndns.. Here's a link for some info on that route.

https://blog.resellerclub.com/how-to-host-a-domain-website-on-your-own/

2: You could use a hosting company like AWS, Azure, or any VPS based hosting solution. This can sometimes cost money and take some time to setup but long term this is a great solution as long as you are willing to put forth the time and effort to learn whatever tech stack you choose. Here's a link to some info on this route with AWS

https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/deploy-nodejs-web-app/

Comment: Thanks! I used heroku for their free hosting